# Is it okay to go for another company after acknowledging an offer letter in email (before joining)?

Tags: ethics, negotiation

I have about 2.5 years of work experience. I recently got an offer from a company in a different city and I have acknowledged in the offer email two days ago. 
Today I got an offer letter from another company in my own city and they are giving more salary than the first. 
Is it okay and ethical to go back on my word and join the second company?

PS- I have never done salary negotiations before in my life so I am not sure how these things are done.

Comment: "*I have acknowledged in the offer email two days ago*" What does that mean? Why are you talking about salary negotiations when the way you've phrased your question indicates that you *accepted* the offer?

Comment: I have accepted the offer from Company A 2 days ago. Haven't joined it yet. 
Got an offer from Company B, who are willing to pay more cause I negotiated for a higher pay..

Comment: Would you buy something because you said you would, even though there's a better sale going on right in front of you?

What purpose would that hold? You haven't accepted a job until you say you have. "Acknowledging" something can mean whatever you or I want... But if you *accepted*, then you are already technically employed.

Comment: Ah. I had a misconception that it doesn't start until you join the company for the first day and sign the papers.

Comment: But if you already employed then it just mean you're quitting, and since you haven't been putting any hours there's no need for two weeks notice.

Comment: If you signed the contract, it means you accepted the contract. If you have _not_ signed the contract, then you have not accepted the contract. Please clarify what you mean by "acknowledge".

Comment: Please share the country as this can vary. One country might have a law that says that accepting an offer in writing is proof of a Contract being formed already and therefore, has to be honoured

Comment: @gnat : The OP isn't asking about negotiating. The question here is whether it's ethical and/or legal to do so. Does "acknowledgment" mean acceptance? Or did the OP actually "accept" the offer and told them that he/she would be joining? That's the part I am unclear about

Comment: I am in India.  And by acknowledge, I mean I replied to the offer letter with " I would be happy to join" . With that, I also mentioned a request for joining bonus for which they haven't responded as of yet.

Comment: Forget the "ethics" aspect.  **Both of the companies would instantly sack you, cut you off at the knees** if they had to for some reason.  Do what is best legally and best in terms of business issues and your overall career.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I shall not go into the ethics of it, as it is subjective, situational and has many complex dependencies on many things.

You should perhaps look at it more from legal lens, did you accept any clause in the offer latter that you cannot renege or there are penalties associated if reneged. Are there any provisions in the law of the land that is generally applied in such cases. If there are no legal constraints you could join the second company legally.

As for the ethics part of it, you alone would be best placed to answer it.